# How I write a separate function in ajax for success method?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How I write a separate function in ajax for success method?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'devices.json',
    data: {},
    datatype: 'JSON',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        var devices = data;
        function print_dev() {
            var str = "";
            str += '<h3>Ajax, JSON Data</h3>';
            document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = str;
        }
        print_dev();
    }
});
```

Can I define the function outside the ajax scope?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - you can interchangeably use anonymous and pre-defined functions:

```
function onDevicesRead(data) {
    var devices = data;
    function print_dev() {
        var str = "";
        str += '<h3>Ajax, JSON Data</h3>';
        document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = str;
    }
    print_dev();
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'devices.json',
    data: {},
    datatype: 'JSON',
    method: 'GET',
    success: onDevicesRead
});
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine with this.